# How to save WPF UI state?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, settings, tabcontrol

I have a `TabControl` and under it I have several elements like `TreeView` and `DataGrid`. When I expand the tree and resize data grid columns, if I then tab to another tab and come back, the entire UI state is forgotten. I have to re-expand the tree and resize the columns.

Is there a sensible and existing way to save the UI state? Let's divide this into -

1. temporary (in memory) and
2. permanent (on the disk).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To save the state you can bind the relevant control(`Width`, `Height`, `IsSelected` etc.) properties to your binding source's properties(i.e. ViewModel in case of MVVM), this will automatically save your temprory state; for permanent saving you can serialize your ViewModel and save it on disk and obviously load it when required.

like for saving your tree view state you can have `IsExpanded` and `IsSelected` properties in the object(ViewModel) that your `TreeView` is bound to like this -

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
    <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
</Style>
```

You can also use project settings for saving state of your application, 
look at this SO Question -

[c# - approach for saving user settings in a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784477/c-sharp-approach-for-saving-user-settings-in-a-wpf-application/3784591#3784591)

and this article - [User Settings Applied](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25829/User-Settings-Applied)

Comment: So, I would put all properties I wish to save into my view model? I think my view model would quickly became bloated. Is there a generic approach to take here -- i.e. I have two tree views so do I prefix the  `IsExpanded` properties like `FooTreeViewIsExpanded` and `BarTreeViewIsExpanded`?

Comment: @rFactor - No, IsExpanded property would go to the Model of your TreeViewItem; look at this article for explanation - [Simplifying the WPF TreeView by Using the ViewModel Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26288/Simplifying-the-WPF-TreeView-by-Using-the-ViewMode)

Comment: @rFactor - and in case you want to save a lot of states of your controls/window then you can use the ProjectSettings approch; see the links provided in answer.

Comment: How do you serialize though? I've tried with:
File.WriteAllText("C:\\Form.txt", jsonSerializer.Serialize<CustomFormModel>(currentForm.ViewModel as CustomFormModel));
The custom type has ~50 properties in it's complete inheritance structure, but that's much less than the native WPF classes. I'm getting OutOfMemoryException on a 32GB machine.