# WPF Restore Visibility State on next start

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to convert my old windows forms code into wpf. Each of my windows stored the visibility state, size and position and restored this states on the next run of the application. I connect to the FormCloseQuery event where it was possible to get information about the closereason. This is not possible in WPF.

I can store the position and size in the WPF forms' closing event, but it's not possible to store the visibility state.

Is there an answer how this can be done?

Thanks
Martin

Comment: These questions can help you:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169103/how-to-save-wpf-ui-state

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784477/c-sharp-approach-for-saving-user-settings-in-a-wpf-application?lq=1

Comment: @cellz, *how* do you think either of your linked questions would help with their problem regarding the `Visibility`, or did you not read this question?

Answer (score 1):

> I can store the position and size in the WPF forms' closing event, but it's not possible to store the visibility state.

Poppycock! What's wrong with the `Window.Visibility` property?:

```
private void MainWindow_Closing(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    // this.Visibility is the current visibility state of the Window
}
```

Also, for your information, it is a better idea to handle the `Window.Deactivated` event to update the values each time the application goes out of focus, or the `Window.Closed` event to update upon closing. The `Closing` event is specifically for cancelling the close request.

Furthermore, it is also customary in WPF to store `bool` values and then data bind them to the `Window.Visibility` property using the [`BooleanToVisibilityConverter` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Hi Sheridan. Thank for the comment. You are right, I'm using the Closed event not the Closing. The problem is that Closed is called when the window is closed by the user manually or by the application when exiting the application. If it's closed manually I don't want to open the window. If it's closed by the application it should show up in the next step. The CloseReason in winforms helped me out here, but it's not possible to detect how a WPF window was closed.

Comment: *it's not possible to detect how a WPF window was closed*... anything is possible.