# manage a collection of settings in memory with global scope

Tags: c#, wpf, observer-pattern

I have a wpf app and a bunch of read/write settings that need to be accessible from various viewmodels.
a setting can be any type (string, bool, etc) and all are settable, but only from a 'Settings' view.
I also need the viewmodels to be notified when any setting has been updated and which one that was.

Right now I have a threadsafe singleton called Settings and here's some pseudocode:

```
class Settings{
    //singleton standard stuff here...
    public int PropertyX {get; set{ TriggerNotification(thePropertyName) }

    //observer pattern
    public void AddListener(IListener listener) {}
    private void TriggerNotification(){ notify all listeners which setting was changed and with what value }
}
```

My question is, is this a good solution? Should I maybe post this with some real code on the codereview site instead?

Comment: Isn't there a way of doing this built-in to the .NET framework? Is it missing some functionality you need?

Comment: @JeffBridgman maybe there is, but that is also my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3784477/945456