# How do I save inputted text from a textbox to .settings file when a button is clicked WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a small WPF application for installing files. When a button is clicked a window opens prompting the user to input the install path to a textbox and click a button when finished. How do I put this input into the settings file so it can be used app wide? I can provide any code if requested.

PS: I am very new to StackOverflow, so please give me a heads up if I should be doing something differently when asking questions. :)

Comment: Since you can provide any code, perhaps you provide a snippet of what you've tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, a hint will suffice. I think it would be a good idea to take a look at that following classes in order to learn how to save some settings to a file so that you can use it application wide.

- StreamWriter
- XmlSerializer

I think this link would also be useful.

[C# - approach for saving user settings in a WPF application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784477/c-sharp-approach-for-saving-user-settings-in-a-wpf-application)